# how to get parametars from Service to AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask and on the background I want to start  Service that spoused to get the text from url.

I need to know from the service when it done working and get from it some  text and continue with AsyncTask.
But I dont know how to get parameters  from the  Service to AsyncTask and to know if it finished.

my code on  AsyncTask is:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //starts service number activite
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("services.conServise");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

return null;
}
```

the  Service  code:

```
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    // Create some random data
           try{
      URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/index.html");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
     str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        }
        activitNum = Integer.parseInt(str);
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
statusCon=-1;

    }finally{stopSelf();}


    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to start a `Service` when the code in `Service` could easily be written in the `doInBackground()` method. `doInBackground()` runs on a non-UI thread and is meant to do such type of Network activities. So I would suggest that you do all the fetching-of-data-from- network activity in the `doInBackground()` itself rather than starting a `Service`.

Comment: and if  app goes on background?

Comment: in your question you said that you wanted to PAUSE the method `doInBackground()` till the service returned. Now why would you even want to stop a non-UI background thread? Since its not blocking the UI, it can take any amount of time to run. You can start the `Service` separately maybe in `onPostExecute()` if you want it to run after the app goes to background.